# How to change navigation text color on fullscreen scroll based on background?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, parallax

Title says it all really. Here is an example of what I'm trying to achieve [navigation color change image based on background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ifJS.png)

The problem is that it needs to work with a site that's using a scroll-jacking parallax type effect, here is the site I'm trying to achieve this effect with [demo website](http://madebyjordan.webflow.io/)

Answer (score 2):

Modify the scroll script a bit

Check demo **[here](https://codepen.io/jpI/pen/ayNwvz?editors=0111)**

Created the function `toggleHeaderColor` to check the current section. Since the scroll script is indexing each section in order `0 (i.e. section_1) ,1 (i.e. section_2),2 (i.e. section_2),3 (i.e. section_3),4 (i.e. section_2) and so on`. Every time you scroll it gets updated.

In scroll script there are two function `nextItem()` and `previousItem()`form which we get the current slide index and on that we can call our function to toggle `dark` class on header elements.

JS:

```
var sectionBlock = $(".section-item");
var getCurrentSlideAttr = 0;

function toggleHeaderColor(getCurrentSlideAttr) {
  if (getCurrentSlideAttr == 0) {
    $(".menu-link, .menu-link-logo, .menu-link-last").removeClass("dark");
  }
  if (getCurrentSlideAttr == 1) {
    $(".menu-link, .menu-link-logo, .menu-link-last").addClass("dark");
  }
  if (getCurrentSlideAttr == 2) {
    $(".menu-link, .menu-link-logo, .menu-link-last").removeClass("dark");
  }
  if (getCurrentSlideAttr == 3) {
    $(".menu-link, .menu-link-logo, .menu-link-last").removeClass("dark");
  }
  if (getCurrentSlideAttr == 4) {
    $(".menu-link, .menu-link-logo, .menu-link-last").addClass("dark");
  }
}

var ticking = false;
var isFirefox = /Firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var isIe =
  /MSIE/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ||
  /Trident.*rv\:11\./i.test(navigator.userAgent);
var scrollSensitivitySetting = 30;
var slideDurationSetting = 800;
var currentSlideNumber = 0;
var totalSlideNumber = $(".section-item").length;
function parallaxScroll(evt) {
  if (isFirefox) {
    delta = evt.detail * -120;
  } else if (isIe) {
    delta = -evt.deltaY;
  } else {
    delta = evt.wheelDelta;
  }
  if (ticking != true) {
    if (delta <= -scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== totalSlideNumber - 1) {
        currentSlideNumber++;
        nextItem();
      }
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
    if (delta >= scrollSensitivitySetting) {
      ticking = true;
      if (currentSlideNumber !== 0) {
        currentSlideNumber--;
      }
      previousItem();
      slideDurationTimeout(slideDurationSetting);
    }
  }
}
function slideDurationTimeout(slideDuration) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    ticking = false;
  }, slideDuration);
}
var mousewheelEvent = isFirefox ? "DOMMouseScroll" : "wheel";
window.addEventListener(mousewheelEvent, _.throttle(parallaxScroll, 60), false);
function nextItem() {
  getCurrentSlideAttr = currentSlideNumber;
  toggleHeaderColor(getCurrentSlideAttr);
  var $previousSlide = $(".section-item").eq(currentSlideNumber - 1);
  $previousSlide
    .css("transform", "translate3d(0,-130vh,0)")
    .find(".content-wrapper")
    .css("transform", "translateY(40vh)");
  currentSlideTransition();
}
function previousItem() {
  //console.log($(".section-item").eq(currentSlideNumber).attr('id'))
  getCurrentSlideAttr = currentSlideNumber;

  toggleHeaderColor(getCurrentSlideAttr);
  var $previousSlide = $(".section-item").eq(currentSlideNumber + 1);
  $previousSlide
    .css("transform", "translate3d(0,30vh,0)")
    .find(".content-wrapper")
    .css("transform", "translateY(30vh)");
  currentSlideTransition();
}
function currentSlideTransition() {
  var $currentSlide = $(".section-item").eq(currentSlideNumber);
  $currentSlide
    .css("transform", "translate3d(0,-15vh,0)")
    .find(".content-wrapper")
    .css("transform", "translateY(15vh)");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem either. Although I've switched to fullpage.js as I felt the old set up was a bit clunky, so some of this code no longer applies.

Answer (score 2):

## Update

You can actually choose a specific text color over white/black backgrounds using css blend modes.

Example with specific colors (green over white and red over black in this case):

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: black;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n):after {
  background: red;
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  
}

div:nth-of-type(2n + 1):after {
  background: green;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scroll to see effect</h1>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

<strike>I think the only way you would be able to choose the exact partial colors using SVG text or paths.</strike>

A simple example with `mix-blend-mode`:

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

h1 {
  position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: white;
  z-index: 1;
}

div {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black;
}

div:nth-of-type(2n) {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>Scroll to see effect</h1>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

[Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode)

https://css-tricks.com/reverse-text-color-mix-blend-mode/

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding `mix-blend-mode` property.

Add this property to your `.navigation-menu` class

CSS

```
.navigation-menu{
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

Hope this Helps...

Comment: It's a very basic solution, however it is causing the font to look like a boldness effect has been added to it and for background colors other than black or white it causes the text color to change. Preferably I'm looking for a solution that allows me to control what color it changes to on each section.